# Data Structures: what is a fixed size array combined with a (doubly) linked list called?

Tags: data-structures

It's not this question: [Data structure name: combination array/linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956928/data-structure-name-combination-array-linked-list/2960329) since in my case it's not an unrolled linked list.

For fun I thought of the following data structure:

- A fix sized array
- Each array can be `NULL` or have a value, next and previous reference (so there's a double linked list in there).
- The references must be managed in such a way that they always point to the next/previous value (that isn't `NULL` in the array), the exceptions are the head and tail of the linked list.

Visualization (for easier visuals, I'm addressing with letters):

```
val,next,prev
-------------
|NULL       | A
|55, NULL, E| B <-- HEAD
|NULL       | C
|NULL       | D
|42, B, H   | E
|NULL       | F
|NULL       | G
|99, E, NULL| H <-- TAIL
-------------
```

Depending on the uses, the advantages and disadvantages differ I think, but one disadvantage is very clear to me: it takes a lot of memory since I was imagining this as an array with mostly empty values.

I personally call it: the vine. The array seems like a wall that the vine is covering. Is this data structure formalized, if so what would be the name of it?

Comment: It has some similarities with a LinkedHashMap (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) except it preserves array order instead of insertion order, and seems to have less efficient insert/delete generally (as it needs to look ahead and behind to find the next and previous entries). It's not clear to me what advantages this data structure has over a hashmap, a linked list or an array.

Comment: Regarding advantages: in my project I'm using a variation of this data structure to manage orders from an order book where the index and order price are a multiple of 10, 100, 1000, etc. depending on the security. And I was simply wondering: is it possible to get everything to O(1)? This was the first idea I came up with. I ultimately settled for something else related to this (as this didn't fully suited my needs), but combining a linked list with an array like this, I just thought: this must have been done before and have a name.

Comment: You might want to look at skip lists (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). Not O(1), but fairly efficient at scanning over data sets with arbitrary gaps.

Comment: This kind of embedded linked list s often used to keep track of free elements in the array, and is called a "Free List" in that context: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_list

Comment: @MelvinRoest I believe you are looking for [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html). It doesn't supports NULL though, but you can have custom defined 'NULL' values.

Comment: 1) Thanks for skiplists :) 2) I do see how this looks like a free list, that's funny. 3) I'll checkout ArrayDeque.